# How do I control the time format in an input field?

Tags: c#, datetime, asp.net-core-mvc

My model has a datetime-field:

```
public DateTime ProjectStart { get; set; }
```

If I want the time to be displayed in 24-hours format, as plain text in a view, I can do this (with capital HH):

```
@Model.ProjectStart.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm")
```

But how do I control the time format in an input field?

```
<input asp-for="ProjectStart" class="form-control" />
```

The time is stored in the database 24 hour formatted. It is just the input field that is displaying it wrong. It should display date and time in this format:

> dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm (e.g. 28/02/2019 17:45)

My app's culture (`CultureInfo.CurrentCulture`) is `nb-NO`, which is correct. The standard format for date and time in this culture is the one I'm trying to display in the input fields. ([Norwegian date and time formats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_and_time_notation_in_Norway))

**UPDATE**

I have tried two solutions, with no luck:

Decorating the property in the viewmodel:

```
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm}")]
```

Adding the tag helper attribute `asp-format` in the input tag:

```
<!-- I tried several variations of this: -->
<input asp-for="ProjectStart" asp-format="{0:dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm}" class="form-control" />
<input asp-for="ProjectStart" asp-format="{0:dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm}" class="form-control" />
<input asp-for="ProjectStart" asp-format="{0:dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm}" class="form-control" />
```

Both solutions just cleared out the value in the input field, displaying only "mm/dd/yyyy --:-- --", i.e. the format was not changed, and the data disappeared.

**UPDATE 2**

This is the rendered HTML of the input tag with the `asp-format`-attribute:

```
<input class="form-control" 
       type="datetime-local" 
       data-val="true" 
       data-val-required="The Starttidspunkt field is required." 
       id="ProjectStart" 
       name="ProjectStart"
       value="12.10.2019 07:12" />
```

As you can see, the format is correct, and the data is there. But in my browser, the datepicker displays "mm/dd/yyyy --:-- --".

Comment: Can you post the rendered HTML from your input tag? Using the `asp-format` attribute.

Comment: @mxmissile See update 2. The fomat is correct in the HTML, but the datepicker in Chrome displays "mm/dd/yyyy --:-- --".

Answer (score 1):

Use `asp-format` tag helper attribute, for example:

`asp-format="{0:yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm}"`

```
<input asp-for="ProjectStart" class="form-control" asp-format="{0:yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm}" />
```

The format string must adhere to the subset of ISO-8601 date formats specified in [this W3C document](https://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime).

Comment: That changes the content of the input field from "10/09/2019 09:45 PM" to "mm/dd/yyyy --:-- --".

Comment: The desired content is a full `DateTime`, date and time, but no seconds or milliseconds, with 24 hours time format. Like so: "10/09/2019 22:05"

Comment: `asp-format="{0:dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm}"` displays `09/10/2019 14:12`

Comment: Not for me. Could there be something else interfering with the formatting? Chrome? My computer's system settings? I don't have any formatting decoration in the viewmodel.

Comment: More than likely culture settings. It's really just a matter of finding the `formatstring` that works with your culture. Replace `dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm` with the correct string.

Comment: I'm sorry ", kl" should not be in there. I just use that for displaying the dt in plain text. The format for the input field should be `dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm`. But no matter - that doesn't work for me either.

Comment: What does this output? `DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm", new CultureInfo("en-us"))`

Comment: The correct formatting: "09/10/2019 23:08". But the property for the inputfield is a `DateTime`, not a `string`... I should add that the time is stored in the database as 24 hour format.

Comment: Right I get that, however that proves that your culture setting is not compatible with that formatstring, we forced the culture to US which format's it correctly. Don't force your culture in your app, this was just a test.

Comment: What culture is your app running under? Probably a good place to start. `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` should tell you.

Comment: `nb-NO`, which is the right one, and the standard date format for that culture is the one I'm trying to display.

Comment: Try  `"dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm"`

Comment: Nope. Same result. Just clears out the data. Format remains the same.

Comment: I forced my culture to nb-NO and it worked for me. I just don't know enough about culture settings and such, sorry I wasn't more help. I'll keep this answer here for the time being, so no one else tries the same thing, might ring a bell with someone that knows more. Be interesting to see the outcome.

Comment: Thank you for your efforts! Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

When you apply the `[DataType(DataType.Date)]` attribute, Razor renders the input with a type of "date". This is an HTML 5 input type, it will be rendered as a browser control (the calendar you get by default). However, the browser control  forces that the date will be displayed localized (i.e. `MM/dd/yyyy` in the U.S.).That is to say,the format shown in the broswer depends on the local date format.

So,if you want to show the format `dd/MM/yyyy`,you need to change your local system date format.You could refer to the following link to learn how to change the local date format.

Reference:https://www.moore.co.uk/msuk/moore-stephens-south/news/may-2016/has-upgrading-to-windows-10-affected-your-date-for